# Maximum value of $x$ in this right triangle's edge

Tags: geometry, triangles

> In a triangle $\triangle{ABC}$ $\measuredangle{BAC}=90^{\circ}$. $D$ is the midpoint of $BC$ and $E\in AC$. $|ED|=x+6$ and $AB=3x-4$. For condition $|AE|>|EC|$, find maximum integer value of $x$.

Here is a diagram for the question:
[image]
Let $|DC|=k$ and since $|DC|=|BC|$ we can conclude with angle transportations:
$$
|DC|=|BD|=|AD|=k
$$
Observe that triangle $\triangle{ADC}$ is an isosceles triangle so $x+6<k$. And with triangular inequality we have $3x-4<2k$. Seems like i can't get any useful data and i have no idea to solve for now. Hints and solutions are appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean $|DC| = |BD| = |AD| = k$?

Comment: @B.Mehta exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F$ be the midpoint of $AC$. Note that $DF\perp AC$ and

$$|DF|=\frac{|BA|}{2}=\frac{3x-4}{2}$$

If $|AE|>|EC|$, then $E$ is a point on the line segment $FC$. So $|DE|>|DF|$.

\begin{align*}
\frac{3x-4}{2}&<x+6\\
x&<16
\end{align*}

The maximum integer value of $x$ is $15$.